# What is the difference between strip_tags and wp_filter_nohtml_kses?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, security, sanitization, wp-kses

What is the difference between [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [`wp_filter_nohtml_kses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses). I tried to figure wp_filter_nohtml_kses from the source but it looks like it does something a bit more complex than strip all html even though thats what the codex says. I think the kses functions are expensive so I wonder why not use strip_tags if all it does is strip the html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technical difference is kinda obvious. PHP one is single function, using logic in PHP code. WP one is one of family of functions, based on third party KSES library.

Is there practical difference between these two specific functions? I think the important point is that `strip_tags()` was made for *utility*, while KSES was made for *security*.

So, while results would likely be close in most cases, I would expect KSES implementation be **slower and more thorough**.

---

I have encountered [comparison of HTML filters at HTML Purifier site](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#Summary), following is excerpt of `strip_tags()` and `kses` (original, non-WP version) summary (there is more there on both):

```
+------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+------------+--------------------------+
|  Library   | Whitelist  | Removal | Well-formed | Nesting | Attributes | XSS safe | Standards safe |
+------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+
| strip_tags | Yes (user) | Buggy   | No          | No      | No         | No       | No             |
| kses       | Yes (user) | Yes     | No          | No      | Partial    | Probably | No             |
+------------+------------+---------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: I see what you are saying about the kses functions being designed for security, but if strip_tags actually strips all the tags then do you mean that strip_tags might possibly miss some html tag? Or are we thinking that that evil code might somehow get around strip_tags. I dont really understand why I'd use wp_filter_nohtml_kses if it's expensive to run and strip_tags does the same thing?

Comment: @byronyasgur I don't have any specific examples or reference right now, but my vague impression is that `strip_tags()` is indeed not absolutely reliable to remove all tags, especially on very malformed HTML. I might be completely mistaken on this, so I'd suggest to make question about how reliable it really is on Stack Overflow.