# wp_kses vs wp_strip_all_tags

Tags: wp-kses

Apart from providing a granular control for allowed HTML tags does `wp_kses` provide any additional benefits over `wp_strip_all_tags`? Essentially, if I were to use `wp_kses` and set it to `not` allow any HTML or protocols, would it carry any benefit over just using `wp_strip_all_tags`?

Comment: The difference seems not so clear cut. You may want to have a look at this [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45280/what-is-the-difference-between-strip-tags-and-wp-filter-nohtml-kses) and its [accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45288/83173). This may also be interesting: [http://mikemclin.net/wp_kses-better-php-strip_tags/](http://mikemclin.net/wp_kses-better-php-strip_tags/).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call it a benefit or disadvantage, but more of a difference: `wp_strip_all_tags` simply strips all tags (except for the allowed tags) but does not delete their content by calling the PHP function [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), after removing `script` and `style` tags in full, **including their contents**. `wp_kses` does no such thing:

```
// Returns 'alert( "test" )' (content of script tag)
wp_kses( '<script>alert( "test" );</script>', array() );

// Returns '' (empty string)
wp_strip_all_tags( '<script>alert( "test" );</script>' );
```

So, if you were to use `wp_kses` and set it to not allow any HTML, it would differ from `wp_strip_all_tags` in that it would not remove the content of `script` and `style` tags.

Comment: According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#refsect1-function.strip-tags-examples), the `strip_tags` function does not seem to remove tag content. Does it?

Comment: Exactly. I've clarified this in my answer, should it not have been clear enough already.